# What is wrong in declaring data type of variable inside while loop but not inside for loop?

Tags: java

If I declare variable then initialize variable inside while loop, there is no problem.

```
int a; 
while((a=someValue)!= -1)`
```

But if I declare variable and initialize it inside while loop, there is problem in compile time.

```
while ((int a=someValue) != -1)
```

What is the reason for this? Declaring and initializing variable seems to be fine in For Loop though.

## Full Code snippet:

#### correct one

```
int a;
while ((a=Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine())) != -1) {
    sum.addNumber(a);
}
System.out.println("sum: "+sum.sum());
```

#### wrong one

```
while ((int a=Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine())) != -1) {
        sum.addNumber(a);
    }
System.out.println("sum: "+sum.sum());
```

Comment: The difference is the second one doesn't compile. The reason for that is that the second one has invalid syntax.

Comment: is it not like `int a;` `a=5;` to `int a = 5;`?

Comment: `while` takes an _expression_ the evaluates to `true`. `a = 5` is an expression that evaluates to `5`, so `a = 5 != -1` evaluates to a `boolean`. `int a = 5` is a statement.

Comment: Perhaps the Tutorial might illuminate.

Comment: Sorry, but simply read a book. Or a good tutorial.

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you explain how one is statement while the other isn't?

Comment: I would suggest you read a tutorial.

Comment: Every language has different syntax rules. For Java, you can see will not work. In C or other languages, the difference will be related to the scope of that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second will already give a syntax error. Unlike **For** loop, you cannot declare a variable in a **While** loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can only write an expression inside the parenthesis of a `while` loop. Semantically, this makes sense: suppose you declare a variable inside `while()`, then on each iteration it will create a new local variable, and you can't declare a local variable more than once.